# Java selenium read java script popup values

Tags: java, selenium

Please take a look at this page: `https://bitly.com/2wokiu4+`

While the `Mouse` is over this blue chart there is some text that i want to read and compare it to another value on this `Page` (`CLICK`)

Any idea how can i read this `Value` ?

I try to search it over the `HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below gets all charts with not 0 height, chart clicks count for each, summarizes all and compares with clicks amount in the top right corner.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

int clicks = Integer.valueOf(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("info-wrapper--clicks-text"))).getText());

List<WebElement> charts = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".highcharts-series-group rect:not([height='0'])")));

AtomicInteger totalChartClicks = new AtomicInteger();

charts.forEach(webElement -> {
    actions.moveToElement(webElement).perform();
    int amount = Integer.valueOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.highcharts-tooltip span:nth-of-type(2)")).getText().replace("Total Clicks ",""));
    totalChartClicks.addAndGet(amount);
});

Assert.assertEquals(totalChartClicks.get(), clicks);
```

Comment: Can you explain please the charts.forEach ?

Comment: You can find explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)